# How to display firebase realtime multiple child into recyclerview with cardview?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have made it like this but nothing appears in the Recyclerview layout

i get a logcat message

No setter/field for Pemeran found on class com.example.dbMovieAdapter
No setter/field for Episode found on class com.example.dbMovieAdapter

if I add it to the model use variable string, I get the logcat message again

message : Arrays is not supported, please use Listsinstead

Firebase Realtime Database Structure

```
"app" {
      "SerialDrakor" {
                  "1" {
                   "Episode" {
                      "1" {
                           "LinkMovie" : "linkfirebasestorage/url.mp4"
                           "List" : "1"
                      }
                    "Pemeran" {
                      "1" {
                           "NamaPemain" : "Tukiyem Marni"
                           "FotoPemain" : "linkfirebasestorage/file.jpg"
                      }
```

**DrakorAcivity**

```
private RecyclerView mEpisodeRV,mPemeranRV;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbMovieAdapter,DrakorActivity.ListEpisode> mListEpisodeAdapter;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbMovieAdapter, DrakorActivity.ListPemeran> mListPemeranAdapter;

String judul,sinopsis,genre,tglMulai,akhirepi,updateepi,thumbnail;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_drakor);

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SerialDrakor").child("Episode");
mEpisodeRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cRecylerDrakorEpisode);
mEpisodeRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

//This is Code For Episode
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<dbMovieAdapter> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<dbMovieAdapter>().setQuery(databaseReference,dbMovieAdapter.class).build();

    mListEpisodeAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbMovieAdapter, DrakorActivity.ListEpisode>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(DrakorActivity.ListEpisode holder, int position, final dbMovieAdapter model) {
            holder.setList(model.getList());
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final String url = model.getLinkMovie();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", url);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public DrakorActivity.ListEpisode onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_drakor_episode, parent, false);               
            ListEpisode holder = new ListEpisode(view);
            return holder;                
        }
    };

 //This is For Pemeran
 DatabaseReference aDrakor = database.getInstance().getReference("SerialDrakor").child("Pemeran");
    Query PemeranQuery = aDrakor.orderByKey();
    mPemeranRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cRecylerDrakorPemeran);
    mPemeranRV.hasFixedSize();
    mPemeranRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions aPemeranOption = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<dbMovieAdapter>().setQuery(PemeranQuery, dbMovieAdapter.class).build();
    mListPemeranAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbMovieAdapter, DrakorActivity.ListPemeran>(aPemeranOption) {
        @Override
                 protected void onBindViewHolder(ListPemeran holder, int position, final dbMovieAdapter model) {
            // holder.setTitle(model.getJudul());
            holder.setNamaPemain(model.getNamaPemain());
            holder.setFotoPemain(getBaseContext(), model.getFotoPemain());

        }
        @Override
        public DrakorActivity.ListPemeran onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_drakor, parent, false);

            return new DrakorActivity.ListPemeran(view);
        }
    }; 

    mEpisodeRV.setAdapter(mListEpisodeAdapter);
    mPemeranRV.setAdapter(mListPemeranAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mListEpisodeAdapter.startListening();
    mListPemeranAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mListEpisodeAdapter.stopListening();
    mListPemeranAdapter.stopListening();

}

//ViewEpisode
public static class ListEpisode extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public ListEpisode(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setList (String list){
        TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.TxtlistEpisode);
        post_title.setText(list);
    }
}

//ViewPemeran
public static class ListPemeran extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public ListPemeran(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setNamaPemain(String namapemain){
        TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.drakorpemainNama);
        post_title.setText(namapemain);
    }
    public void setFotoPemain(Context ctx, String fotopemain){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.drakorpemainGambar);
        Picasso.get().load(fotopemain).into(post_image);
    }
}
```

**dbMovieAdapter**

```
public class dbMovieAdapter {
    private String Sinopsis;
    private String Thumbnail;
    private String TglNewEpisode;
    private String TglTayang;
    private String AkhirEpisode;
    private String Judul;
    private String Media;
    private String Tujuan;
    private String Video;
    private String List;
    private String Genre;
    private String Subtitle;
    private String FotoPemain;
    private String NamaPemain;
    private String LinkMovie;


    public dbMovieAdapter(String fotopemain,String namapemain,String linkmovie,String subtitle,String sinopsis,String thumbnail, String tglnewepisode ,String tgltayang,String akhirepisode, String judul, String media, String tujuan,String video, String list) {
        this.Sinopsis = sinopsis;
        this.Thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.List = list;
        this.TglNewEpisode = tglnewepisode;
        this.TglTayang = tgltayang;
        this.AkhirEpisode = akhirepisode;
        this.Judul = judul;
        this.Media = media;
        this.Tujuan = tujuan;
        this.Video = video;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        //baru
        this.NamaPemain = namapemain;
        this.FotoPemain = fotopemain;
        this.LinkMovie = linkmovie;



    }
    public dbMovieAdapter(){

    }
    public String getNamaPemain() {
        return NamaPemain;
    }
    public void setNamaPemain(String namapemain) {
        this.NamaPemain = namapemain;
    }

    public String getFotoPemain() {
        return FotoPemain;
    }
    public void setFotoPemain(String fotopemain) {
        this.FotoPemain = fotopemain;
    }

    public String getLinkMovie() {
        return LinkMovie;
    }
    public void setLinkMovie(String linkmovie) {
        this.LinkMovie = linkmovie;
    }

    public String getSinopsis() {
        return Sinopsis;
    }
    public void setSinopsis(String sinopsis) {
        this.Sinopsis = sinopsis;
    }

    public String getTglNewEpisode() {
        return TglNewEpisode;
    }
    public void setTglNewEpisode(String tglnewepisode) {
        this.TglNewEpisode = tglnewepisode;
    }

    public String getTglTayang() {
        return TglTayang;
    }
    public void setTglTayang(String tgltayang) {
        this.TglTayang = tgltayang;
    }

    public String getAkhirEpisode() { return AkhirEpisode; }
    public void setAkhirEpisode(String akhirepisode) { this.AkhirEpisode = akhirepisode; }

    public String getJudul() {return Judul; }
    public void setJudul(String judul) {this.Judul = judul; }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {this.Thumbnail = thumbnail; }
    public String getThumbnail() {return Thumbnail; }

    public String getMedia() {return Media; }
    public void setMedia(String media) { this.Media = media;}

    public String getTujuan() {return Tujuan;}
    public void setTujuan(String tujuan) {this.Tujuan = tujuan;}

    public String getVideo() {return Video; }
    public void setVideo(String video) {this.Video = video;  }

    public String getList() { return List; }
    public void setList(String list) { this.List = list;  }

    public String getGenre() {return Genre; }
    public void setGenre(String genre) {this.Genre = genre; }

    public String getSubtitle() { return Subtitle; }
    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {this.Subtitle = subtitle;}

}
```

Comment: Please add the content of your `dbMovieAdapter` class.

Comment: I added it, sir :)

Comment: after adding a follower in the post that you provided with the property name, nothing will appear on the recyclerview

Comment: and i still get the logcat message : No setter/field for Pemeran found on class com.example.dbMovieAdapter No setter/field for Episode found on class com.example.dbMovieAdapter

Comment: Please remive old data and add fresh one.

Comment: do you mean sir ?

Comment: To delete the actual data and add fresh one so you have the new fields.